# Webpack2 triggers compilation end event many times instead of once

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I'm using Webpack in watch mode to build my server code and I want to execute something when Webpack finishes bundling (ie. compilation finished and everything is done).
However I can't figure out what is the right way to accomplish this.
I tried that:

```
import baseConfig from './webpack.server.babel.js';

class TestPlugin
{
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.plugin('done', (stats) => {
            console.log('Event fired.')
        });
    }
}

export default {
    ...baseConfig,
    watch: true,
    //stats: "errors-only",
    plugins: [
        new TestPlugin(),
    ],
}
```

but when I run Webpack event `done` executes many times, here is an example of console output:

```
> webpack --config myconfig.js
Event fired.
Hash: 320187c8b46b56f02ffb
Version: webpack 2.6.1
Time: 60ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
server.js  4.46 kB       0  [emitted]  main
Event fired.
Event fired.
Event fired.
... and ~30 more lines ...
```

After that Webpack is watching for changes and event executes only once when I change something in code.
What is the problem there? Why does it call `done` so many times on cold start?